# Shows image path rather then the image, within one-line if..else statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following line of code:

```
<%= "Brand: " + (@user.activated ? "image_tag('brand1.png', class: 'branding')" : "image_tag('brand2.png', class: 'branding')") + "(#{@user.activated_at})" %>
```

It should show (where the image shown depends on whether user is activated):

> Brand: {image} 6-19-2015

Instead of the image, it displays the literal image path (so text). How should I adjust my code to show the actual image instead?

Comment: Remove quotes surrounding `image_tag`s.

Comment: Then it doesn't recognize it as an if-else statement. So as a consequence it displays both image paths (so again the paths/text and not the images themselves).

Comment: I took a more precise look: you have a typo: `@user.activated? ? image_tag('brand1.png', class: 'branding') : image_tag('brand2.png', class: 'branding')`: function to call is `@user.activated?` with closing question sign, another `?` goes for ternary if.

Comment: I'm afraid adding the '?' and removing the " still displays the path instead of the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a really weird way to write some erb template code.  As @mudasobwa says you have quotes around the image tags which is wrong, and adding lots of strings together in the erb tag is messy, fragile and unreadable. The two image tags are almost identical so could be dried up as well.

I would do what i think you are trying to do like so:

```
<% graphic =  @user.activated ? "brand1.png" : "brand2.png" %>
Brand: <%= image_tag(graphic, class: 'branding') %> (<%= @user.activated_at %>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following one in a single tag, with `html_safe`

```
<%= "Brand:  #{(@user.activated ? image_tag('brand1.png', class: 'branding') : image_tag('brand2.png', class: 'branding'))} (#{@user.activated_at})".html_safe %>
```

Or a more smarter way like

```
<%= "Brand:  #{image_tag(@user.activated ? 'brand1.png' : 'brand2.png' , class: 'branding')} (#{@user.activated_at})".html_safe %>
```